# WPF create button with custom content template

Tags: c#, wpf

I have application in WPF where I need to create a number of buttons with the same content layout.  It is currently defined in the Window as:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="4" >
    <Button.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.85*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.25*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Primary Text that can wrap" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14.667" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextAlignment="Left" Text="smaller text" FontSize="10.667" />
        </Grid>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

What I would ideally like to do is change that to:

```
<controls:MultiTextButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" PrimaryText="Primary Text that can wrap" SecondaryText="smaller text" />
```

Rightly or wrongly I've created the following class:

```
public class MultiTextButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PrimaryTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PrimaryText", typeof(String), typeof(MultiTextButton));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondaryTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SecondaryText", typeof(String), typeof(MultiTextButton));

    static MultiTextButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MultiTextButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MultiTextButton)));
    }

    public string PrimaryText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PrimaryTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PrimaryTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public string SecondaryText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SecondaryTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SecondaryTextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I'm now unsure of how to set the 'template' to display the content in the format as the original code in the Window.  I've tried:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MultiTextButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type controls:MultiTextButton}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.85*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.25*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding PrimaryText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14.667" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding SecondaryText}" FontSize="10.667" />

    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

but in Blend and Visual Studio the button is not rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're after [`TemplateBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx):

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding PrimaryText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14.667" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{TemplateBinding SecondaryText}" FontSize="10.667" />
```

This binding is for use specifically in control templates -- it refers to a dependency property in the control.  (Note that a regular binding, by contrast, refers to a property in the current `DataContext`.)

---

**Edit**

To make it look like a button, copy the [default control template for `Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx) and replace its `ContentPresenter` with something like below:

```
<ContentControl Margin="2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}">
    <ContentControl.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.85*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.25*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding PrimaryText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14.667" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding SecondaryText}" FontSize="10.667" />

        </Grid>
    </ContentControl.Content>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Almost there!... I can now see the primary and secondary text but it doesn't look like a button.  It looks like two text blocks.  It there a way to get the template in the content of the button?... Do I need to copy the 'regular' button template and just stick in my content where the content presenter would be?